# What does Website Performance refer to exactly?

Tags: performance, responsive-design

I was reading various articles regarding `Responsive Web Design` and I came across how important website performance is for a good user experience, however I cannot understand what exactly is meant by website performance except of course a fast loading time?

Answer (score 0):

With responsive design, being responsible means only loading resources that a particular device needs. You wouldn't necessarily send very large images to a small mobile device, for example, nor would you load heavy JavaScript for apps that don't apply on a particular device.

> What Causes Poor Performance?
>
> Most of poor performance is our fault: the average page in 2012 weighs over a megabyte. Much of this weight comes form blocking assets like Javascript and CSS that prevent the page from being displayed.
> The average size of images on a Web page is 788KB. That’s a lot to send down to mobile devices.
> Javascript, on average, is 211KB per transfer. This comes from the libraries and code we choose to include from third party networks. This cost is always transferred to our users. We need to stop building things for developer convenience and instead build them for user experience.
> 86% of responsive designs send the same assets to all devices.

http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1684=

Answer (score 0):

Website performance from a user point of view generally means loading time + displaying time + fast response for user actions ...but in fact it is much more complex.
From designer point of view you need to worry about limited part of the problem - just try to make your designs less resource-consuming (data size, no. of requests, CPU, memory, user actions).

There's a lot of knowledge out there - this article might be interesting for you:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/rules_intro

Answer (score 0):

Ilya Gregoriks talk [Breaking the 1000ms Time to Glass Mobile Barrier](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Il4swGfTOSM) explains that latency on mobile is a big issue. Every additional request has a dramatic impact compared to non-mobile.

On top of the loading time i assume that the different cpu speed on mobile must be considered. If the page feels sluggish due to havy javascript use the mobile user will not use your page. Also a few pages i visited did not work on my android tablet; since the marketshare of mobile is increasing every page that does not take this into account will loose visitors